# Controller observer is not triggered using ajax request

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, ajax

I am using this event:
`controller_action_predispatch_sales_order_create_showUpdateResult`

this is my xml code:

```
    <controller_action_predispatch_sales_order_create_showUpdateResult>
        <observers>
            <mynamespace_mymodule_controller_action_predispatch_sales_order_create_showUpdateResult>
                <class>Mynamspace_Mymodule_Model_Observer_MyClass</class>
                <method>myMethod</method>
            </mynamespace_mymodule_controller_action_predispatch_sales_order_create_showUpdateResult>
        </observers>
    </controller_action_predispatch_sales_order_create_showUpdateResult>
```

This is my class:

```
class Mynamspace_Mymodule_Model_Observer_MyClass
{

    public function myMethod($observer)
    {
        Mage::log('Tralala', Zend_Log::ERR, 'mylog.log', true);
    }
}
```

This is the controller from ajax :`sales_order_create/showUpdateResult/`. It s about updating the items from cart from adminpanel. I would like to trigger an observer when that ajax request is called. For some reason it doesn;t work. What am I missing ?

Thank you

Comment: have you tried to print route name in your controller ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved my observer form `<adminhtml>` to the `<global>` and changed my event from

```
<controller_action_predispatch_sales_order_create_showUpdateResult>
```

to

```
<controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_sales_order_create_showUpdateResult>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding:

`<type>singleton</type>`

along with `<class/>` and `<method/>`.

I'm not sure what the default value of **type** is, but the examples given in Magento dev docs set it to "singleton".